# Symfony error ajax when redirect in KernelRequest

Tags: php, symfony

I have a problem in my KernelRequest. First of all, users have a list of privileges associated to a profile. In backoffice, admin can create many profiles and what features they can access.

For example, if my user go to /profil/me. My KernelRequest will check if he can access to the path /profil. If is not, I redirect the user in home.

Unfortunately, this does not work with ajax calls... I use fullcalendar and in my console, I have this message:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <  router.js:9 
Uncaught Error: The route "fullcalendar_loader" does not exist.
```

The redirect works fine, BUT I always have this message, why?

```
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    $session = new Session();
    $routeToRedirect = 'home_index';
    $user = $session->get('JUNGO2_UTILISATEUR');
    $profil = $user->getProfil()->getId();
    $routeInterceptName = $event->getRequest()->get('_route');
    $routeInterceptPath = $this->router->getRouteCollection()->get($routeInterceptName);

    if (HttpKernel::MASTER_REQUEST != $event->getRequestType() || $routeInterceptName == "app_security_login" || $routeInterceptName == "home_index"){
        return;
    }
    // if user are not in home
    if ($routeToRedirect != $routeInterceptName) {
        // For a profile, we list all privileges 
        $profil = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Profil')->findOneById($profil);
        $privileges = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Privilege')->getPrivilegeByProfilNotNull($profil);
        $routeInterceptPath = $routeInterceptPath->getPath();
        //We retrieve the first word after the '/''
        // Example: if the route is /user/profil, we just retrieve /user
        $t = explode("/", $routeInterceptPath);
        $routeInterceptPath = "/".$t[1];


        // We look at whether the url corresponds to one of these privileges
        foreach ($privileges as $privilege) {
            $route = $privilege->getRoute();
            $route = $this->router->getRouteCollection()->get($route)->getPath();
            if($routeInterceptPath == $route){
                return;
            } 
        } 

        // ERROR WITH AJAX
        $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate($routeToRedirect));
        $event->setResponse($response); 
    }
}
```

If I remove the two last lines for the redirection, I no longer have the error messages. But of course, there is no more redirection...

You have an idea of ​​what is wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [**access controls**](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/access_control.html)? After that, you can handle this with **roles**.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how I can use the security.yml access control. Administrators can create roles directly in the back office and associate to these roles which routes he can access .

I have 3 entities ( and of course the table associative):

Roles with just a name

Privileges with the route like /profile or /admin

Permissions with a boolean

This may not be the best solution, but I found nothing else.
I already use Access control in another project, but with only 3/4 static roles.